# Displaiyng JComponent objects - Java

Tags: java, swing

During my first days working with Java and Swing I encountered one problem, which I don't understand. Here is my code below.

import javax.swing.*;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class MyFrame 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
         {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Frame f = new Frame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                }
          });

    }
}

class Frame extends JFrame{
    Frame()
    {
        Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension size = kit.getScreenSize();
        int screenwidth = size.width/4;
        int screenheight= size.height/4;
        setSize(screenwidth,screenheight);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        World panel = new World();
        panel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        add(panel);


        setVisible(true);

    }
}

class World extends JComponent{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("String1", 70,70);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics c)
    {
        Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,16);
        c.setFont(font);
        c.drawString("String2", 30, 40);
    }
}
```

I don't understand the action of my second class called World. I expected that I got both String1 and String2 but on my window I can see only String2. What is the reason ?

Comment: You should avoid overriding `paint` for this very reason.  You've broken the paint chain, prevent `paintComponent` from been called. Also remember that `JComponent` is transparent by default, so failing to call `super.paintComponent` is going to cause you issues. Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details...

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the parent class's paint() method normally calls the paintComponent() method. Since you're overriding the paint() method and not calling super.paint(), it no longer reaches the code that calls paintComponent().

There are other things in the paint() method that you shouldn't be screwing with, so generally it's a good idea to only override paintComponent().

Comment: And even then call `super.paintComponent()`

Comment: +1, See the section from the Swing tutorial on a [Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html). Read the entire section for examples on the proper way to do custom painting.